# iOS, Facebook app posting only by ME

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Am I missing something. I'm creating the app where user is able to take a picture, edit it and post it to facebook. I have created app on developers.facebook.com, inserted keys into my iOS app. I can login and post a image on my profile, no problems at all. It says nicely "few minutes ago via --My App--" and it works perfectly.

I'm posting using:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:message forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:@"picture"];
//disable button

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error)
 {
     if (error)
     {
         //showing an alert for failure
         [self showAlert:@"Facebook unable to share photo " result:result error:error];
     }
     else
     {
         //showing an alert for success
         [self showAlert:@"Facebook share photo successful" result:result error:error];
     }
 }];
```

and like I said, it works perfectly for me. I gave the app to my friend, he logged in normally, app asked for permission, everything cool. Took a picture, clicked post, waited for upload and the app gave him alert that image is posted successfully "Successfully posted 'Facebook share photo successful'. Post ID: something", BUT the image never appeared on his wall. So far, I'v tested only with that other account (I will test it with more accounts, but I'm not sure what am I missing).

What should be configured in the app settings on the facebook so that everyone can use my app? Is it because app details are not yet submitted to facebook or because I didn't set iPhone AppStore ID - because app is not on store yet?

//-------------------- EDIT 1 ---------------------

Image is there, it's being posted! Album is being created and it says that there is some image inside but the preview is not shown. When a user goes into that album, pictures are visible and user is being asked to approve those images. If the user approve, images are normally visible and the actual wall post is being posted. How can I override this?